# What's the maximum swap memory in Linux

Tags: php, linux, memory, swap

today I discovered what was swap memory on linux, after a PHP error "`cannot allocate memory in...`", "`The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured`". So I searched a bit and found the `free -mt` command.

```
$ free -mt
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3855         445        2725          83         684        3072
Swap:          2047         584        1463
Total:         5903        1030        4188
```

The code above show that a swap memory has already been configured, with approximatively 2GB, for a RAM of about 4GB. On that [RedHat page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-swapspace#:%7E:text=Swap%20space%20in%20Linux%20is,a%20replacement%20for%20more%20RAM.), we can see the swap memory amounts based on RAM :

```
Amount of RAM in the System Recommended Amount of Swap Space
4GB of RAM or less      a minimum of 2GB of swap space
4GB to 16GB of RAM      a minimum of 4GB of swap space
16GB to 64GB of RAM     a minimum of 8GB of swap space
64GB to 256GB of RAM    a minimum of 16GB of swap space
256GB to 512GB of RAM   a minimum of 32GB of swap space
```

My question is, how works the swap memory, could I increase it without decrease the base memory ? I also saw that we could add a second swap memory. It is the server of my work on which a lot of programs are running, I don't want to make mistake or brake something, that's why i post here.

PS : I'm a beginner with Linux servers, and also sorry if my english is a little bad :)

Thank you !

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. You can increase it. If, however, all your RAM is used up linux starts to swap out still-used memory and your whole system might become slow. REALLY slow.

Comment: This is more a server question than PHP. Serverfault or linux/unix (https://unix.stackexchange.com) may be better. Swap uses HD space instead of RAM, it goes to that when RAM is used up. It should be used as a reserve, if your hitting RAM limits often you should increase RAM

Comment: It's more than the **swap** size, Linux also manages swap via **vm.swappines** which dictates when swap should be used, see for example this [article](https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/)

Comment: Not that you have the option to use a `swapfile` similar to windows swapfiles. No need to keep an entire partition allocated. *Note: have not tried that*

Comment: If it's an on-premise physical server, it would be better to buy and install more RAM. Swap is significantly slower than memory.

Comment: isn't maximum memory available to php is set in php.ini memory_limit? I think its possible to have 32gb RAM and set php's memory limit to just 200mb

Comment: @Kristian Yes, but the error message is about server memory availability not the script executing. Also if a script really needs 32 GBs it is likely a bug.